# Can we set a timeout for the Eclipse function hint list?

Tags: eclipse, code-hinting

is it possible to set a timeout for the Eclipse function hint list?

Waiting for the full function list to load simply pisses me off...:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can trigger the content assist immediately by hitting Ctrl-Space.

Second, you can set the delay under Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Auto-Activation. Non-Java editors may have separate settings. You can type search terms on top of the prefence window to see all related settings.

Comment: I'm looking for more of a timeout setting, but +1 and thanks anyways! Cuz I sometimes regret calling content assist and wish the process could kill itself.

Comment: @Littledot: I'm not sure what you mean then, perhaps you should describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: When the function list pops out, my Eclipse simply hangs until the whole function list is finished processed. It takes about 10~20 seconds on the first call and 5~10 for any subsequent calls. This irritates me alot! So I am looking for a setting that could stop the processing of the whole function list - a timeout setting.

Comment: @Littledot: there's something wrong with your eclipse setup or your project then. Are you using the newest version? Do you see errors in the eclipse log file in .metadata?

Comment: My logs are filled with `org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Project target not loaded yet.` & `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null` I'll check those out, thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight! Fixed those nasty exceptions, now my Eclipse is smooth and slick! Thanks for teaching me to check .metadata!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add on this by pointing out that I was facing the same kind of issue in Eclipse Mars Version `4.5.0 M1`.

I got this error :

[image: error seen]

I managed to solve it by disabling the following setting "Code Recommenders proposals" from `Window\preferences\Java\Editor\Content Assist\Advanced`

Disable it from both `Default proposal kind` and `Content cycling` . Restart eclipse , and the error is gone.

I don't know why this happens, or what the addon does. Maybe someone can elaborate on it.